# How to analyze country specific data with 40 data points?

Tags: continuous-data, small-sample

I have country specific aggregated data with 40 data points. My independent variable is the availability of health care facilities and dependent variable is infant mortality rate. I tried using linear regression to observe the association but model assumption of constant variance of residuals was not fullfilled.

Which model should I use to analyze this dataset?

Comment: We need more information.  What question are you trying to answer and what data do you have available?

Comment: We rarely, if ever, care about normality of the independent variable, and when we do care about normality of the dependent variable, we mean the conditional distribution (the error term), not the marginal distribution of all of the $y$ values pooled together.

Comment: My exposure variable is health care facilities available and outcome variable is infant mortality rate in different geographical regions. I'm not sure how should I analyze these variables.